# Is it a good practice to have only shared functions/methods in a class?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Sorry for the long title. Here is a sample situation that I encounter often with windows forms applications. Much of the code in my application is centred around the UI so it so happens that most of my code is in the main class (MainWindow). Here is an analogy of how I am planning to break up my code. I will have to write a compressed file to the disk when the user performs an action. So it would look like this. Is this a good practice. This is just an attempt to organize my code better.

```
Public class MainForm

    Private Sub TempButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TempButton.Click
         Compression.CompressFile(fileStream)
    End Sub

End Class


Public Class Compression

     Private Sub New
          'Private constructor
     End Sub

     Public Shared Sub CompressFile(ByVal inFile as stream)

     End Sub

     Public Shared Sub DeCompressFile(ByVal inFile as stream)

     End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This question might be better suited for the code review forum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a common pattern.

However, such functions should go in a `Module` (or `static class` in C#).

Comment: If they're relevant to the class, what is to be gained by keeping them separate?

Comment: @RobbieDee: Relevant to which class?

Comment: If the shared functions relate solely to the class, then by definition, they belong to the class - not in a separate module or static class...

Comment: @RobbieDee It sounds like a utility function to me, which doesn't really **belong** to any class, so it's generally cleaner to put it in it's own.

Comment: If they relate solely to the class, they belong to the class. Having general purpose utility modules/class goes against the general ethos of OO. It sounds like what he/she is describing is really a singleton so to cut a long story short, a class full of shared functions is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @RobbieDee True, this "utility class" would not be used by any other classes. All the calls to its members are solely from the main class. The reason I was thinking on those line was to manage and find my code better.

Comment: There is a singleton template here which might help: http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/dsgnsigleton.htm

Answer (score 0):

If a method of a class doesn't need an instance of the class object, then it is good practice to make the methods Shared.

Comment: Yes, I'm agreeing with him/her... :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good practice to have **only** shared functions/methods in a class?

No. Usually developers call these helper classes. It may look ok in be beginning, but soon down the line these helper classes grow like crazy and contain lot of responsibility. These helper classes are static in nature. These voilate SRP (single responsibility principle) of OO design. I call them God classes. They know everything :)

You should prefer to have a common base class or abstract class instead.

Comment: Actually, this is very common and perfectly acceptable. It is called the singleton pattern.

Comment: I know. I'm one of those who consider singleton evil :)

Comment: The problem is a lot of inexperienced coders write such helper classes in the singleton style which helps nobody...

Comment: I myself consider helper classes evil... :)